# RSQLite only pretends to write to a database table with a bracketed name

Tags: r, database, dbi, rsqlite

I want to write data to a table called `[foo/bar]` inside of a SQLite database created through `RSQLite`. I wrote the following function to save answers to disk.

```r
save_to_disk = function(data) {
  con = dbConnect(SQLite(), "responses.db")
  path = "[foo/bar]"
  message("Writing the data now!")
  message("The database file size was: ", file.size(response_db))
  dbWriteTable(con, path, data, append = TRUE)
  message("Table append complete!")
  message("The database file size is now: ", file.size(response_db))
  dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

However, when I try to pass this function data I see:

```
Writing the data now!
The database file size was: 8192
Table append complete!
The database file size is now: 8192
```

If I change the table name to `dummy` and repeat the process, then instead I see:

```
Writing the data now!
The database file size was: 8192
Table append complete!
The database file size is now: 12288
```

It seems as though RSQLite doesn't like my table name for some reason. My understanding was that this was a valid table name since it was wrapped in `[...]`. In fact, outside of that function I am perfectly able to write to such a table. In other words, this works from the REPL:

```
test = data.frame(submitted = as.integer(Sys.time()), 
                  respondent = "Alice", 
                  subject = "Alice", 
                  question = "name", 
                  part = "first", 
                  order = 1L,
                  answer = "Alice")
dbWriteTable(con, "[foo/bar]", test, append = TRUE)
```

After that I can use `dbReadTable` to see what I had just entered. Why doesn't it work the same way in a function?

Comment: Rather than look at file size, did you verify data was actually inserted into the table? Try checking file size after database connection is closed.

Comment: Yeah, the first thing I did was look for the data with `dbReadTable`.  I only looked at file size as a way to confirm within the function that it was doing something.

Comment: I ran a test, and got the same result with `"dummy"` or `"[foo/bar]"` as a name: the file size is only modified _after_ closing the connection, in both cases. I adjusted the example to make it reproducible with `response_db <- tempfile(fileext = ".sqlite")` and `save_to_disk(iris)`

Comment: Hmmm....I tried your code with empty SQLite table and ran a `dbReadTable` after `save_to_disck` call and the table reflected inserted data frame even though file size in messages were exact same. Ran entire code again and table doubled. So I cannot reproduce. Also, as I thought, moving `dbDisconnect` before second message, file sizes do change.

Comment: Also, the behavior is the same inside and outside a function. Please make the example reproducible to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: I tried again on another operating system and yes it does seem to work without issues. The operating system I was using before was CentOS7.

Comment: I also noticed upon testing on the different operating system that the size of the database doesn't necessarily change according to `file.size`.

Comment: One potential lead for why things might not have worked the same on the CentOS7 system was that the file system was NFS.